# framework7 navigation issue in firefox

Tags: spring, navigation, phonegap, html-framework-7

- in firefox whenever I refresh the page, automatically it redirects to main-view page (home page),

  - after refreshing page, it should keep me on current page
  - but it show main-view page (home page) View
  - and in url it shows current url but visible page is home page
- i have not redirected to main-view page (home page) from any page

Example:

- home URL      : http://www.test.com/
- Current URL   : http://www.test.com/#!/searchedResult?value=ip

steps to reproduce

- go to any page URL other than home
- refresh page

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure only to enable hash navigation on the Home View (if you have multiple views/tabs)?
Here is how I initialize my view

```
var homeView = app.views.create('#view-home', {
  url: '/',pushState: true, stackPages: true
});
```

And here is how I set the PushState Root on my app:

```
views:{
stackPages: true,
  pushState: true,
    history: true,
    pushStateRoot: location.href.split(location.host)[1].split('#!')[0],
},
```

My app.js looks like this: (Look out how I've set the view parameter after the touch parameter)

```
    var app  = new Framework7({
   
  root: '#app', // App root element
  id: 'your.pkg.id', // App bundle ID
  name: 'My App', // App name
  theme: 'auto', // Automatic theme detection
  version: 'BETA',
     touch: {
        tapHold: true,
        fastClicks:true,
        materialRipple:true,
        activeState: true,
        disableContextMenu: false,
       },
       
        statusbar: {
    iosOverlaysWebView: false,
  },
views:{
stackPages: true,
  pushState: true,
    history: true,
    pushStateRoot: location.href.split(location.host)[1].split('#!')[0],
},
    data: function () {
    return {
      user: {
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
  },
  // App routes
  routes: routes,
});



var homeView = tyappy.views.create('#view-home', {
  url: '/',pushState: true, stackPages: true
});
var catalogView = tyappy.views.create('#view-catalog', {
  url: '/catalog/', stackPages: true
});
```